# Jqplot stacked bar chart live update

Tags: javascript, ajax, jqplot

I want to update the live date with Jqplot stacked bar chart. I have tried by the following way, but I cannot update the series.

```
plot3.series[0].data = da1;
plot3.series[1].data = da2;
plot3.series[2].data = da3;
plot3.series[3].data = da4;
```

Comment: What happens / what error do you get with this code?

Comment: I have checked with browser console also but i did't get any error.The chart gets displayed at the first time.But after the first refresh x-axis gets displayed but the chart not getting displayed.Also i cannot get any solution for refreshing Jqplot stacked bar chart at any link.

Comment: did you call the replot function on your jqplot object?

Comment: Yes, I made call of plot3.replot() function as last line in my method.

Comment: Now i found the solution.For JqPlot bar chart the above way is working fine,but for JqPlot stacked bar chart,I have tried the following way.var series = [da1,da2,da3,da4]; plot3.replot({data:series}) its working fine for stacked bar chart.Thank you so much for all your respone